# upload videos with filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

I want to allow for video uploads from a user's computer or if possible all available network sites.  I am currently using the trial versions.  Is it possible to do video uploads using file picker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should specify the mimetype as "video/*"

Comment: thanks brett.  Is it possible for users to upload videos from social networks in this way as well?

Comment: We currently support video uploading from Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, Evernote, FTP, Webdav, Web cam, and url, but not yet Facebook or Picasa